# How to fix trust error with two Active directory Domains

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

There are two Domains and there is a trust between both domains, this works fine for a long time but now we get access denied errors. So I open "Domains and Trust" and validate the Trust between both domains. In the following dialog there is shown following error:

```
The secure channel (SC) verification on Active Directory Domain Controller \\pdc.site1.company.tld of domain site1.company.tld to domain site2.company.tld failed with error: Access is denied.

The secure channel (SC) reset on Active Directory Domain Controller \\pdc.site1.company.tld of domain site1.company.tld to domain site2.company.tld failed with error: Access is denied.

The secure channel (SC) verification on Active Directory Domain Controller \\pdc.site2.company.tld of domain site2.company.tld to domain site1.company.tld failed with error: Access is denied.

The secure channel (SC) reset on Active Directory Domain Controller \\pdc.site2.company.tld of domain site2.company.tld to domain site1.company.tld failed with error: Access is denied.
```

Next I reset the trust password and enter the credentials from a Domain-Admin of the other Domain and get the following errors:

[image: the parameter is incorrect]

and

[image: the trust cannot repaired]

The same Issue occurs if I try it from the other DC. I have checked the conditional forwarders, that looks good. I also delete the Trust on each Domain and recreate the trust level, but the same issue. How can I solve this trust issue?

Both DC run with Windows Server 2008 R2 in Domain functional level Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I had this same issue yesterday. The fix I eventually stumbled on was to use Netdom to reset the trust.

Eg:

for domains abc and xyz - with appropriate usernames and passwords

on a domain controller in Forest domain (in admin cli)

**netdom trust /d:abc xyz   /verify  /Uo:username /Po:password /Ud:username /Pd:password**

and then in the other (child) domain the reverse - switch the usernames etc...

**netdom trust /d:xyz abc /verify  /Uo:username /Po:password /Ud:username /Pd:password**

and that worked - machines could validate and group policy started working again.

(We were getting "cannot bind to ldap server" errors when doing a gpupdate from one of our child domains).